# change event in JQuery doesn't trigger at first

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am quite new to jQuery. I am using it for one of my WordPress plugin. I have following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tmp-preview").html($("#title").val());
    $("#title").change(function(){
      $("#tmp-preview").html(getTweetPreview);
    });
  });
</script>
```

I want that every time text in title textfield of wordpress new post's page changes, it should reflect into a div. But the problem is, that event doesn't trigger on first change. I mean, if user write a title for first time and move focus to other part, that title is not updated in div. But then again if he changes the title, new title does reflect! Why does this happen like this?

And another thing I would like to know is, if I want that even though the focus in text field is not lost, title text get updated in div on each character's change, do I have to use keydown event or I can do it with change event somehow?

PS: Problem isn't with getTweetPreview() function. I have already tried using a simple string but still same. I believe this is happening due to some other function calls of wordpress as when title is finished editing, it auto save the draft. Can this be the issue? How to solve it, if it is?

Comment: The `.change()` jQuery function just executes `.onchange()` browser function, which is not valid for `<title>`.

Comment: for the second query : you can not fire `keyup` and `change`  event together. it will get stuck in some browser

Comment: Can you post the relevant `HTML`?

Comment: I didn't mean that title tag. I mean while writing a new post in wordpress, title text field.

Comment: @PraveenKumar where does OP talks about `<title>`

Comment: Hey man whats : getTweetPreview ?

Comment: @diEcho Okay, in that case `onchange()` works only for `<select>` tag and not for anything else...

Comment: `getTweetPreview` seems to be a function *pointer*, so try replacing it with `getTweetPreview()`

Comment: @jSang relevant html would be just a text field with id="title".

Comment: @AlvinWong Already tried. Issue isn't with that function. I have already tried using some simple string instead of that but still same

Comment: @PraveenKumar first of all it not `onchange`. its `.change()`  This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements. For **select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons**, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

Comment: @ksg91 . Please make a [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net) for relevant HTML code. there may be some Markup mistakes

Answer (score 3):

This may work:

```
$("#title")
    .on(
        "input", 
        function () {
            $("#tmp-preview").html(getTweetPreview); 
        }
    );
```

Try something like this if everything else fails:

```
var updateTweetPreview = function () { // DRY
    $("#tmp-preview").html(getTweetPreview); 
};

$("#title")
    .one( // sic.
        "keydown", 
        function () {
            updateTweetPreview();
            $("#title").on("change", updateTweetPreview);
        }
    );
```

Comment: If it the cause is Wordpress doing a check out and updating the content this will not prevent the autosave feature.

Comment: This wasn't the exact solution because it doesn't tell why in my code, change event is not being fired. However this will work instead of my code, so I am awarding bounty. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem. :) Issue with your code might be browser related.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the `on()` function for events. `live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 [source](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

As for the actual problem, I think that WordPress' auto save is using ajax to load a copy of the data into the form when autosave is complete. That would cause your code to have it's contents overwritten. Try putting this in:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tmp-preview").html($("#title").val());
    $("#title").on("change", function(event){
        event.stopImmediatePropagation()
        $("#tmp-preview").html(getTweetPreview());
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the live method

```
$("#title").live('change', function(){
  $("#tmp-preview").html(getTweetPreview);
});
```

For more information on live [Click here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: `.live` is deprecated from `jQuery 1.7` use `.on`. but OP did not mention the version of jQuery

Comment: isn't live deprecated? I already checked that but as it was deprecated, i didn't try. They recommend using .on event. Let me try that.

Comment: @diEcho I use 1.7.2 version of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Where is gettweetpreview coming from? Cos this seems to work every time:

```
$("#tmp-preview").html($("#title").val());
$("#title").change(function(){
  $("#tmp-preview").html($(this).val());
});
```

​Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TNrPZ/

Comment: As I mentioned in my PS, WordPress auto saves the draft on first change using jquery. So is it possible that it is preventing to execute my own code from executing at first?

Comment: Strange - even if there is an additional change function happening - they should both fire. Perhaps your function is changing it, but the WP function changes it back directly after. try changing it to `$("#tmp-preview").css('background-color','red');` to see if it is targeting the right div or something stranger is going on.

Comment: tried that. Same happens, no effect at first. Anyway if I was targeting wrong div, it shouldn't work other times.

Answer (score 0):

If `getTweetPreview` is a function, then you should be calling it rather than just referencing it. The code would look like:

```
$("#title").live('change', function(){
  $("#tmp-preview").html(getTweetPreview());
});
```

The only difference here is the inclusion of `()` after `getTweetPreview`.

Comment: getTweetPreview is a function which returns a string to be put in that I have tried all the possibilities like this. Even, instead of the function i used a static string but it happens like this. Issue is that it doesn't work only first time when event is triggered. Rest of the time it works. It looks like WordPress' autosave is acting culprit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `keyup` event from the `jQuery` to have the content of your div updated without loosing the focus from the textbox.

**Try this code**.

`$("#tmp-preview").html($("#title").val());
    $("#title").keyup(function(){
        $("#tmp-preview").html($(this).val());
});`

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen, and what fixed it was to *call* `focus()` on the element.  Try making the *call* to `focus()` the very last thing done before the event occurs.